# Logging a big Powershell Script

Tags: logging, powershell

I'm writing a big script for a server install, and I want it to be fully automatic, but also want developers to be able to fix it if it breaks (because it probably will!). To do this I imagine using Write-Output, Write-Debug, Write-Verbose, Write-Warning.

How do I get all of these Writes to be written (and time-stamped) to a .txt file? Also, I know that usually Write-Error is usually written in red, but there's no color in .txt files. Is there a way to help distinguish them anyways, like maybe giving them a prefix to all the writes, like Debug, Warning, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, come on ! Why do you use text file old fashion logging that scatter information all over the operating system and need to be collected with tweezers by people who are in charge of the production ?

As PowerShell works on .NET you can use [Even Tracing for Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sergeim/archive/2008/12/10/how-to-do-etw-logging-from-net-application.aspx) (ETW) or use the system log.

You can create and use one PowerShell log for all your scripts to publish details of the execution (information) and errors (in coordination with good exception handling) for people who are in charge of the production. You can dedicate a log for one script (as it exists a log for DNS etc.)

Here is an example (PowerShell V2 has it's own CmdLets) :

```
# List of logs
Get-EventLog -list

# Creating your own log
New-EventLog -LogName "SlxScripting" -Source "MaSource"

# List of logs
Get-EventLog -list

# Writting in your own log
Write-EventLog -LogName "SlxScripting" -EventId 12 `
               -Message "Mon Message" 
               -Source "MaSource" -EntryType Warning

# Reading (consuming) in your own log
Get-EventLog -LogName "SlxScripting"  

# Suppressing your log (if needed)
Remove-EventLog -LogName "SlxScripting"
```

Comment: This does look like an all-around upgrade (except for the bulkier syntax). Now regarding your link on ETW, can that be used in PowerShell?

Comment: I think it can be. I use use it in some of my native (Win32) program in order to instrument the code so that I can turn on a kind of debug in realease version (in production). Not sure that PowerShell scripts really need that.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would just be useful for if I neglect to write something to events.

Answer (score 3):

`Write-(Error|Debug|Verbose)` do not support writing to file unfortunately. So I created this Write-Log function to address this shortcoming:

http://poshcode.org/3270

Some example usages:

```
Write-Log -Message "It's all good!" -Path C:\MyLog.log -Clobber -EventLogName 'Application'
Write-Log -Message "Oops, not so good!" -Level Error -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "My Script"
Write-Log -Message "Just another example" -Level Warn
```

Comment: Oh, okay. Can you tell me what's going on in this file from [PoshPAIG](http://poshpaig.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/856ae80565cc)? https://gist.github.com/2886029 He seems to be logging using Verbose, Warn, and Debug. Is he not logging?

Comment: any lastests version for Write-Log by Andy Arismendi (for use with Powershell Remoting)? What is about too using PoshPAIG "logging" ?